# Using correct version of Jersey but servlet.ServletContainer class not found

Tags: java, rest, jsp, servlets, jersey

I am using Jersey to build a RESTful Web API and I am running into some problems.

I used [Jersey archive 1.19](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) and I corrected the error of servlet-class and param-name mentioned in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941615/jax-rs-tomcat-runs-normally-but-root-not-found-404). But the class not found still exists.

This time the jsp page I created is able to visit with no 404 error. I did not implement any content to it.

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>AllegiantWS</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>allegiantWS.rest.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My project name is AllegiantWS. What could be wrong?

Comment: Make sure the jars are actually getting built into the war. They should be in `WEB-INF/lib` inside the war

Comment: Share URL by which you are viewing JSP and 2nd by which you are getting 404

Answer (score 0):

**url-pattern** and **@PATH** seem to be in consistent:

```
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
```

This tells container that all requests with http://[Hostname]/api to be redirected to this servlet.

```
@Path("/v1/status")
```

The rest controller will handle requests of form http://[Hostname]/v1/status